# Extending django user model and errors

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

django 1.8.2

**this is my model:**

```
class AppUser(AbstractUser):
    _SEX = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    _pregex  = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone    = models.CharField(validators=[_pregex], max_length=16, blank=True)
    gender   = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, choices=_SEX)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True)
    vericode = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True) # verification code over SMS?
    verified = models.DateTimeField(null=True) # datetime stored when verification happened

    @property
    def age(self):
        today = date.today()
        return today.year - self.birthday.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (self.birthday.month, self.birthday.day))
```

**this is my settings:**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# register externals
EXTERNAL_LIBS_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "_externals", "libs")
EXTERNAL_APPS_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "_externals", "apps")
APPS_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "apps")
sys.path = ["", EXTERNAL_APPS_PATH, EXTERNAL_LIBS_PATH, APPS_PATH] + sys.path

# TEST PATH
TEST_ASSETS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "_test")

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'suit',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'cacheops',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'djoser',
    'consents'
)

# Custom model for Auth
# AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'consents.AppUser'
```

**my folder structure is this**

```
app
  -settings.py etc
apps
  -consents
```

In settings.py I added apps path: 
APPS_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "apps") to sys.path,

*when I run python manage.py syncdb (or anything else) I get this:*

```
(cmr) F:\_Projects\cmr\containers\backend>python manage.py syncdb
F:\_Projects\cmr\.venv\cmr\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py:321: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.contrib.contenttypes.generic is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9. Its contents have been moved to the fields, forms, and admin submodules of django.contrib.contenttypes.
  return f(*args, **kwds)

SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AppUser.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'AppUser.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AppUser.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'AppUser.user_permissions'.
consents.AppUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AppUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AppUser.groups' or 'User.groups'.
consents.AppUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AppUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AppUser.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
```

**If I uncomment this line in settings**

```
# AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'consents.AppUser'
```

I get another error:

```
ValueError: Dependency on unknown app: consents
```

I just need to add few fields to default User model (don't want a new create a totally new auth class subclassign AbstractBaseUser)

**So what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Do you really need to inherit from `AbstractUser` and not `AbstractBaseUser`?

Comment: yes, it's faster way. I'm not changing authentication, just adding fields to User model. I don't like 'profile' solution, because I need to integrate with djoser package

Comment: Well, you should definetly uncomment the line in settings.py that tells Django to use your custom user, that's what's triggering the huge error. Let us deal with the other one now....
Problem is that you have two concrete models based on the same abstract model, and foreign key or many to many fields are clashing in their `related_name`.

Comment: Try: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'apps.consents.AppUser'`

Comment: it didn't work, it allowed only single . in value. So I had to add the path for apps to sys.path

Comment: Hmm, if you want to keep your applications in an `apps` submodule, you just need to reference applications like this: `apps.consents`, everywhere (including `INSTALLED_APPS`). I wouldn't recommend changing the `path` that way, just use absolute imports relative to the project root. I keep my apps inside an `apps` submodule myself, however I need to refer to them as `apps.myappname.models` or `apps.myotherappname.views`, etc...

Comment: the problem then is here AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'apps.consents.AppUser' - django doesn't allow this to happen (getting ValueError)

Comment: Yes, you are right, my mistake. I have this in my code: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**solution**

1. Was to erase, re-create db
2. Remove *.pyc files
3. Remove migrations folders

then python manage.py makemigrations worked perfectly.

Comment: I had the same issue. I was just thinking that this would be the solution. Glad it worked for you, now I'm going to try to do it too.

Comment: this worked well for me too